# Pie Timer with jQuery

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

I need to achieve this:

[image]

and the closest plugins I found are:

- [PieTimer](https://github.com/knorthfield/pietimer)
- [TimeCircles](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/index.html)

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RsKR2/1/

```
$('#timer').pietimer({
    timerSeconds: 10,
    color: '#d00',
    fill: '#f00',
    showPercentage: true,
    callback: function() {
        // alert("yahoo, timer is done!");
        $('#timer').pietimer('reset');
    }
});
```

just not sure how to customize the circles/canvas to achieve the desired look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsKR2/7/)**

Edited some css property for desired results

```
#timer {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    -moz-border-radius:0.7em; /* Newly added line */
    -webkit-border-radius:0.7em; /* Newly added line */
    border-radius:0.7em; /* Newly added line */
    border:2px solid #ccc; /* Newly added line */
}

.pietimer > .percent 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.05em;
    left: 0;
    width: 3.33em;
    font-size: 0.3em;
    text-align:center;
    display: none;
    z-index:10; /* Newly added line */
    font-weight:bold; /* Newly added line */
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The center shows percentage, any idea how can I show the seconds?

Answer (score 3):

My Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4aV9/1/) .

The updated Fiddle by [Amit Soni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831454/amit-soni) works only for 10 sec.
the change must be :

```
 var secs = (data.timerSeconds)*((100-percent)/100);/*NEW*/
    $this.find('.percent').html(Math.round(secs)+'');/*Changed*/
    if (data.showPercentage) {
      $this.find('.percent').show();
    }
```

instead of :

```
$this.find('.percent').html(Math.round(percent/10)+'');
        if (data.showPercentage) {
          $this.find('.percent').show();
        }
```

Comment: Even one more UPDATE : instead of Math.round use Math.ceil